# Match URL-Pattern in XSLT 1 Attribute using XPATH

Tags: xpath, uri, xslt-1.0

Have this given piece of RDF/XML (can’t change it…):

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:cel="http://namespaces.semaworx.org/content#" xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:i18n21="http://apache.org/cocoon/i18n/2.1">
<cel:page>
<dct:hasPart>
  <cel:Element rdf:about="http://resources.semaworx.eu/content/element/start_navigation_home">
    <cel:hasStructureI18n rdf:parseType="Literal"><i18n21:translate><i18n21:text key="start_navigation_home">Start</i18n21:text></i18n21:translate></cel:hasStructureI18n>
    <i18n21:key>TheI18nKey</i18n21:key>
  </cel:Element>
</dct:hasPart>
</cel:page>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Now I need to XSLT template-match specific "i18n21:key"-Elements based upon the URI in the "cel:Element"’s "rdf:about" attribute.

Best approach this far was something like
"cel:Element[contains(@rdf:about,'element/start_navigation_home')]/i18n21:key"

So this is an excerpt from the XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="dct:hasPart" mode="layoutject_navigationMain_top">
<header id="navbar">
    <nav>
        <xsl:if test="$device != 'phone'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cel:Element" mode="layoutject_languageSwitch"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cel:Element" mode="layoutject_navigationMain_inlineContent"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </nav>  
</header>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cel:Element" mode="layoutject_navigationMain_inlineContent">
<ul id="main">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cel:Element[contains(@rdf:about,'urbanHOTBED/element/start_navigation_home')]/i18n21:key" mode="layoutject_navigationMain_singleItem" />
</ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cel:Element[contains(@rdf:about,'element/start_navigation_home')]/i18n21:key" mode="layoutject_navigationMain_singleItem">
<li class="ff">
    <a href="/" title="back to Homepage" i18n21:attr="href title" class="nav_start">
        <xsl:value-of select="cel:Element[contains(@rdf:about,'element/start_navigation_home')]/i18n21:key"/>
    </a>
</li>
</xsl:template>
```

It’s only the *last* template, which won’t match as hoped for.

This far, I have tried being less specific in the "apply-templates" clause, as well as matching the full URI instead of using "contains".

Comment: Your Xpath works for me. What is your question about? To match, it is just `<xsl:template match="cel:Element[contains(@rdf:about,'urbanHOTBED/element/start_navigation_home')]/i18n21:key">...</xsl:template>`.

Comment: THAT’s the problem – MY result is empty i.e. is rendered *without* the template…

Comment: can you post your xslt? what is your environment, xslt processor?

Comment: I’m on Apache Cocoon 2.2 for this project; the processor is XALAN.

Comment: Sorry, this is not an reproduceable example. Please make an example, where the problem still exists and i can copy-paste-run it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t – as soon as I isolate it, the issue goes away. ;-) Obviously I am hindering the match somewhere else. But how can this be ?